# CGS Flush WIndows - pygame error

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, pygame

I was programming a simple chess game, and using the module pygame with python 2.7.3 (32 bit)

I'm using a Mac OS X Mountain Lion (64 bit) and Eclipse + Pydev as IDE

Until yesterday, I was using pygame normally and everything behaved as expected, although I got a warning; however I didn't worry too much since it appeared to be normal in Mountain Lion and, after all, it was working properly

Then, at a certain point and without having modified the code in a meaningful way (and without installing anything new) , it shows this error:

```
MacAntonio.local Python[303] <Error>: The function `CGSFlushWindow' is

obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a 

library it uses, is using this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing to an overal     

degradation of system performance. Please use `CGSFlushWindowContentRegion' instead.
```

I noticed that this message first appeared few seconds after the midnight, October 10, though i have no idea if this is related or not

I searched the internet and I can't find someone who has the same error; a lot of warnings, but this is preventing the code from running at all

If you need I can post snippet of my code.

Thanks everyone

EDIT:

I want to make it clear that this problem does not arise because of some fancy stuff I write, but also with this:

```
import pygame
pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))
```

So it appears that pygame is not working at all in Mountain Lion (I mean, at least for me, but i have a standard configuration and, once again, it worked until 10 October)

Comment: It appears to be an issue with mountain lion and several softwares that rely upon CGS Flush window.. That may be unfixable until new versions of the packages are released, but how the hell one explain that literally from one second to another the code stopped working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough, the issue simply went away and it works now. Interestingly, I did not make any other trial; I left the old installation of Python, Eclipse and PyGame. Didn't change path, imports, or anything.

I have to think it was all a dream!